# How do I get shell/ruby to make a noise (make my computer beep or play a sound/track) when my script breaks?

Tags: ruby, shell, audio, scripting, error-handling

I'm running a testing script that runs over a website over and over again that runs hundreds of times over the course of several hours. I would like for ruby to starting playing a loud song/mp3 for example, to alert me while I'm in a different part of my fairly small apartment.

Comment: What's your OS or music player of choice?

Comment: On MacOS: `afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Funk.aiff`. More: https://superuser.com/questions/598783/play-sound-on-mac-terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also on mac there is the `afplay` program, so it would be possible to do something like:

```
sleep 180 # sleep 3 minutes
`afplay my_song.mp3`
```

Answer (score 12):

I've found THE solution for all Mac OSX users. Credits to this blog post: http://www.mitchchn.me/2014/os-x-terminal/ for showing it to me:

Mac terminals have a command called `say`. `say` functions exactly like one might hope:

```
say "I'm done master"
```

does just that from the terminal.

Inside of a ruby script (in my case) this is easy to implement.

```
`say "I'm done master"`
```

works like a charm.

OK, I'd rather it be a female voice by default, but this is great.

To switch the voice go to System Preferences > Dictation and Speech > Text to Speech > System Voice

Vicki is probably the best sounding female voice

edit: oh yes, I wanted the computer to make a noise when it crashed. To do that in ruby:

```
def go(x)
  begin# starts rescue block
    puts "5/#{x} = #{5/x}"
  rescue
    `say "something is wrong, master."`
  end
end

go(0)
#=> ...
```

Comment: Use `say -v ?` to see a list of voices.  Specify them with, e.g. `say -v Fiona "Let's do this"`.  See more options with `man say`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking to play some music after an exception, just wrap your statement in a `begin rescue` block and when you catch the exception, run something like this (on *nix):

```
pid = fork{ exec 'mpg123','-q', file }
```

or if you're on windows:

```
require 'win32ole'
player = WIN32OLE.new('WMPlayer.OCX')
player.OpenPlayer(file)
```

So it should look something like

```
def methodThatFails  
  begin  
    # Your code here 
  rescue  
    pid = fork{ exec 'mpg123','-q', 'nevergonnagiveyouup.mp3' }
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For windows users: use the gem win32-sound, no mp3 support but .wav

```
# gem install win32-sound

require 'win32/sound'
include Win32

Sound.play("SystemAsterisk", Sound::ALIAS) # play system asterisk sound
Sound.beep(600,200) # play a beep 600 hertz for 200 milliseconds
Sound.play("trompet.wav") # play a file from disk
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gem [`exception_alarm`](https://github.com/pioz/exception_alarm) to play a mp3 alarm file when an exception is raised on your Ruby code.

```
require 'exception_alarm'

alarm do
  # your code...
  raise 'play alarm sound'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`puts "\a"`

If you are developing a command line app and need a simple terminal beep use the following, pure ruby, no libraries, just using ansi escape code. Should work on native terminals (ansi compatible sucha as mac terminal gnome/kde terminals, term2, ssh sessions, tmux, etc. Not sure about windows terminals - it should be supported since is a well known ansi sequence.It will sound just like when you press DELETE or DOWN arrow at the beginning of the input. Hope it helps